# Why Is Outlook Not Sending Emails From My Primary Alias?

Tags: office365

My email address was initially set up as firstname@domain.com.

I added an alias from the Office365 Admin Center as first.last@domain.com.

I then set first.last@domain.com as the primary alias.

I logged out and logged in with the new address and when I look at my account details it says first.last@domain.com.

However, when I send an email it still comes from firstname@domain.com.

How do I change the from field in the email so that it says first.last@domain.com?

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR: Wait a few hours for changes to take effect.**

As mentioned in the question, after I had made the changes (and while I was posting this question) the from field was not changing even when I sent email to myself whilst logged in with first.last@domain.com.

However, after lunch a couple of hours later the same test gave different results and now the emails are being sent from first.last@domain.com.

It seems like it takes about 2 hours for the changes to fully propagate (although some other anecdotal evidence has said 24-48 hours).

Obviously this delay makes it difficult to tell if you have made the change incorrectly or if you are just waiting for caches to update!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have set correctly the default account,
to set the default email account for *New Email* do :

1. Select *File > Options > Mail*
2. Under *Send Messages*, check the box "Always use the default account when composing new messages"
3. Select OK.

Source: 
[Change the account used to send email messages](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-account-used-to-send-email-messages-2bdd8d4f-e30f-4ec8-88a0-406ce7b23cc5)